# How to make Android SDK skip download of already fetched update files during "tools/android update sdk"?

Tags: android, download, facebook-android-sdk

I'm updating Android SDK with

```
tools/android update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force --no-https
```

which takes long time (over night) and got interrupted multiple times no for different reasons (all fixable, so just a matter of patience).

Everytime I restart the command `android update sdk` downloads every file it just downloaded again and I can't believe that there's no use of checksums and caches which can be turned on by (hidden?) option or other configuration parameter. I checked the `android -h` and `android update sdk -h` output.

I'm using Android SDK 2.24.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.